# Database schema for tariffs

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Using the following database schema I'm trying to achieve this...

Each store is on 1 Tariff that has different costs based on the day on the week.

Store 1 is on the low tariff
Monday - Sat - $1.00
Sunday - $0.50

Store 2 is on high tariff
Monday - Fri - $2.00
Sat - $1.00
Sunday - $0.50

There could be hundreds of different variations of these tariffs.

[image: database schema]

Does the schema above achieve this? Recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward tariff table implementation would look like this:

```
Tariff
------
Store ID
Sunday Tariff
Monday Tariff
Tuesday Tariff
Wednesday Tariff
Thursday Tariff
Friday Tariff
Saturday Tariff
```

Your other alternative looks like this:

```
Tariff
------
Store ID
Day of Week ID
Tariff
```

The primary key is the Store ID and Day of Week ID.

Comment: Hi Gilbert Le Blanc the first example you posted would mean that for each store I could be repeating meyself. If i imagine a CMS I would like to pick a named tariff that has been pre-configured

Comment: @Spike: You can save some pre-configured tariff sets to make the selection easier, but you'll find tariff processing a lot simpler if every store has it's own individual tariffs for the days of the week.

Comment: but if i wanted to update a tariff it would mean updating every store, right?

Comment: @Spike: What if you wanted to change the tariff for just one store?  What if a store didn't want to use any of the pre-configured tariff sets?  What if one store needed a 50 cent increase on Saturday?